# jQuery inview only add class to first item in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a blog theme that uses the inview plugin to use J & K scrolling, and also to apply a class to an article that's in view. The only problem is, since I have a mac with a large resolution, there are more than 1 articles in view at a time, so the following script adds the class "inview" to (usually for me, 3 articles) several articles at a time. Is there a way to modify this so it only adds the class "inview" to the FIRST article on the users screen? This may not be the first article on the page, technically, just the first one out of the few in view. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('article').each(function(){
        $(this).bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
            if (visible == true) {
                $(this).addClass("inview");
            }

            else {
                $(this).removeClass("inview");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you can add an index argument to your .each function. Like this:

```
$('article').each(function(index){
        if( index == 0 )
        {
            $(this).bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
                if (visible == true) {
                    $(this).addClass("inview");
                }

                else {
                    $(this).removeClass("inview");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This will add class the class "inview" to the first article.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to jquery.inview.js line 97 where it says

```
$element.data('inview', visiblePartsMerged).trigger('inview', [true, visiblePartX, visiblePartY]);
```

Right before this, add

```
if ($element.prev(".inview").length < 1)
```

So that it checks whether there is an element with class 'inview' before the one for which it wants to trigger the event 'inview' with visible = true.